# how to implement query data on two tables in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

How to implement this query in hibernate?

```
select tab1.name from table1 tab1, table2 tab2 where table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: To answer this, we need to see the entities that map table1 and table2.

Comment: What are the entities mapping those tables? What have you tried? What don't you understand in the Hibernate documentation? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins

Comment: table1 contains columns id,code and table2 contains id,name, repadd,repag. i need to pick all the data from table2 whereever the id match.

Answer (score 1):

Good solution:

There is a relation between the two tables. This relation is one to one, one to many, many to one or many to many. Create this relation in your mapping. If for example table2 is a child of table1, then in the table1 class and mapping you create a property with one of the mentioned relationship, you load only table1 with the HQL statement "from table1" (with optional where-condition; also optionally you can specify the inner join between the two tables), and you access table2 with `table1.getTable2()` (1:1 or n:1 relationship) or `table1.getTable2List()` (1:n or n:m relationship).

Sloppy solution (but absolutely ok if the select is used only in special circumstances):

Do in HQL `select table1.col1, table1.col2, table2.col1 from table1 inner join table2 where ...` and evaluate the list of arrays of object, or alternatively do `select new Tabble1Table2Pojo(table1.col1, table1.col2, table2.col1) from table1 inner join table2 where ...` and evaluate a list of Tabble1Table2Pojo.

Comment: Thanks Johanna. but i have a doubt , how my hbm files look like? can u plz provide table1.hbm.xml and table2.hbm.xml code snippet?

Comment: Have a look here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html there are also many examples in.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(table1.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("table2", FetchMode.JOIN).add(Restrictions.eq("id", 2));
ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
proList.add(Projections.property("name"), name);
criteria.setProjection(proList);
List list = criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use projection api like

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(table1.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("table2", FetchMode.JOIN).add(Restrictions.eq("id", 2));
ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
proList.add(Projections.property("name"), name);
criteria.setProjection(proList);
List list = criteria.list();
```

Also aliases are not used in above example but you can use alias, it's very simple to use.

Comment: hey deepak, thanks for your reply. But what abt my table1.hbm.xml and table2.hbm.xml? do i keep any extra configurations in table1.hbm.xml file of table2.hbm.xml?

Comment: Exactly i don't no what you have doen in hbm files but, i think no need to change/add any configurations in hbm files.

Comment: Also if you refer Johanna's  solution then you have to change or add some configurations in hbm files. I just want to say..there are many solutions for your query in hibernate.

Comment: Thanks i have achieved it but 1 more problem is when i am trying to iterating through list. [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to table1..Can u please help me out.?

Comment: Try this,

List<table1> list = (table1) criteria.list();

if it is still giving same exception you can try casting with table2 also...

List<table2> list = (table2) criteria.list();